# Vaadin - passing data between views

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, view, vaadin

I'm very new in Vaadin and JavaEE at all and I have I think basic question, but will be glad for help.

I have 3 classes in my Vaadin project, here they are:
Main class, responding only for starting and creating navigator:

```
public class MyprojectUI extends UI {


    public Navigator navigator;
        public static final String SECOND_VIEW = "SecondView";

        @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
        @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyprojectUI.class)
        public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
        }

        @Override
        protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
            final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
            layout.setMargin(true);
            setContent(layout);

            ComponentContainerViewDisplay viewDisplay = new ComponentContainerViewDisplay(layout);
            navigator = new Navigator(UI.getCurrent(), viewDisplay);
            navigator.addView("", new FirstView());
            navigator.addView(SECOND_VIEW, new SecondView());
        }

    }
```

And two views class:

```
public class FirstView extends HorizontalLayout implements View {

    TextArea text = new TextArea();
    Button button = new Button("go");

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        this.addComponent(text);
        this.addComponent(button);
        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(MyprojectUI.SECOND_VIEW);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

-

```
public class SecondView extends HorizontalLayout implements View {

    Label label = new Label("Passed text here");

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        this.addComponent(label);
    }

}
```

How can I pass a data from my TextArea to second view? I want set label text to text which was in TextArea when "go" button is clicked.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SecondView secondView = new SecondView();
navigator.addView(SECOND_VIEW, secondView );
Presenter presenter = new Presenter(firstView, secondView);
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you apply Model-View-Presenter pattern. View is already made. Model is not needed here. Just write a Presenter.
In MVP, Presenter is triggered by view, then presenter collects required data from view, does some calculation and updates view. In current case it could look like:

```
class Presenter {
  FirstView firstView;
  SecondView secondView;
  public Presenter (FirstView firstView, SecondView secondView) {
    this.firstView = firstView;
    this.secondView = secondView;
  }
  public void goClicked(UI ui) {
     secondView.label.setValue(firstView.text.getValue());
     ui.getNavigator().navigateTo(MyprojectUI.SECOND_VIEW);
  }
}
```

Code is simplified, recommended practice is define an interface for view instead direct fields access, but main idea is the same.